# Where is a good place to ask questions about PREfast?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-analysis, prefast

Where is a good place to ask questions about PREfast?

Clearly there are limitations to PREfast - some which seem silly:

- it cannot recognize a `CString` as being `const TCHAR *` binary compatible).
- it fails to understand that an `if (FooClass const & foo = FooClass(args))` does in fact initialize foo..
- it complains about ILIsChild() in shlobj.h (which should be corrected @ microsoft)
- requires that the return from _setmode be checked, but the docs for _setmode indicate that it calls invalid parameter handler for an error, and returns its previous mode (utterly useless to check!)
- Incorrectly indicates a mismatch of character count and byte count when using DEVNAMES struct (e.g. wDriverOffset -- which is documented as being count of characters - hence not a mismatch)

Not sure where there are folks discussing the use of PREfast & its bugs & work-arounds?

Comment: P.S. Try PVS-Studio tool. It has more features than the PREfast.

Comment: It looks great... but free vs. $8k us. :(

Comment: @Mordachai did you find any good place? I'm interested, too :)

Comment: The best thing I could find was on code project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167588/Using-PREfast-for-Static-Code-Analysis -- but I couldn't really find a community discussing this technology, just that intro article (though it is definitely a good one).